# C Server - Respond w/ Their IP?

Tags: c

The line:

```
printf("Client IP : [%s]\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```

will print the **Client IP** in the terminal.

I want to put this into the "**response**" so it is sent to the client as well.

instead of responding with "**test**"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "test\r\n";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 85;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    printf("Client IP : [%s]\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out `snprintf()`.

Comment: Basically The answer below seems to be correct but it is measuring the size of "**test**" .. I simply want to over-ride "response" and respond with plain IP. ( needs to measure the size of the IP )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what are you looking for:

```
snprintf(response, sizeof response, "%s", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```

of couse, you need to declare *response* previously with enough size to store the ip address:

```
char response[16];
```

Comment: I was thinking something simple like: **response = inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr);** ( over-writing the response variable )

Comment: the **write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1);** already does the "**sizeof**" stuff.

Comment: Allocate more room for response. Also, you probably mean to use strlen() instead of sizeof() to determine how many bytes to write.

Comment: just declare it as following: `char response [16];` 16 chars should be enough to store an ip address

Comment: @Joey: In C, you can't assign arrays, so `response = inet_ntoa()` won't work. BTW, `[16]` is only sufficient for IPv4.